# Azure openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}

Tags: azure, azure-openai, azure-ai

**openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}**

```
from openai import AzureOpenAI

# may change in the future
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#rest-api-versioning
api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"

# gets the API Key from environment variable AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY
client = AzureOpenAI(api_version=api_version,api_key=api_key,
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/create-resource?pivots=web-portal#create-a-resource
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,)

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-35-turbo",  # e.g. gpt-35-instant
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "How do I output all files in a directory using Python?",
        },
    ],
)
print(completion.model_dump_json(indent=2))
```

Comment: Where did you set "azure_endpoint" value? Do you have a model deployed called "gpt-35-turbo" in your Azure OpenAI resource? And please, use api_version = "2023-12-01-preview" instead of "2023-07-01-preview" as it will be deprecated soon

Comment: azure_endpoint store in os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"] and "gpt-35-turbo" model is deployed.

Comment: Need to give deployment name not model name.